# Save scipy sparse matrix from master node to S3 without pickling first? OOM

Tags: amazon-s3, scipy, sparse-matrix, pickle

I have a large sparse matrix in my master node that I wish to save into S3. I currently do

`pickle_obj = pickle.dumps(sparse_m)`

`s3_client.Object(bucket, s3_path).put(Body=pickle_obj)`

I am running into OOM because the first line creates a pickled version of the sparse matrix, which I think is effectively duplicating the memory usage.

What is a more efficient way to do this without the creation of the intermediate step which creates the OOM?

I could save the sparse object into disk and then send that to S3 outside of the current python session, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this within the same python session without incurring redundancies like I am right now.

Thanks

Comment: `scipy.sparse` has a method for saving a matrix to a `npz` archive.  It saves several arrays that contain the key attributes of the matrix (which depend on the format).  Do you understand the underlying attributes of your particular matrix format?

Comment: @hpaulj yes, this saves to disk, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you save numpy arrays directly to S3?

Comment: @hpaulj not without pickling in memory per my question. Any suggestions? Thanks.